# How to use DialogFlow, node.js v2 library without Firebase

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to figure out how to use DialogFlow with express/bodyParser and the node.js library **v2** functions **without Firebase** (on my own server). I have it working with the request/response JSON data, but I can't figure out what I need to do to use the node.js library function **dialogflow()**. Here's a snippet of what I have that's working with the JSON data:

```
const {config} = require('./config');
const https = require('https');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(config.SSLDIR + 'privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(config.SSLDIR + 'cert.pem'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync(config.SSLDIR + 'chain.pem')
};

const eapp = express();
eapp.disable('x-powered-by');
eapp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
eapp.use(bodyParser.json());

const server = https.createServer(options, eapp).listen(config.LISTEN_PORT, () => {
    console.log(`API listening on port ${config.LISTEN_PORT}. Ctrl-C to end.`);
});
server.on('error', (e) => {
    console.log(`Can't start server! Error is ${e}`);
    process.exit();
});

// I have an Agent class that reads the request object and handles it
eapp.post("/actions", (request, response) => {
    const agent = new Agent(request, response);
    agent.run();
    return;
});

eapp.all('*', (request, response) => {
    console.log("Invalid Access");
    response.sendStatus(404);
});
```

The only solution posted online that I could find said to use the following code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google');
const app = dialogflow();
express().use(bodyParser.json(), app).listen(3000);
```

But I'm confused about:

1. DialogFlow fulfillment requires an https endpoint, so don't I have
   to create an https server like I did?
2. How can I integrate this example into what I've already done to stop
   using the JSON data and start using the node.js functions from 
   **app=dialogflow()** in the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was very simple. I just needed to include the app in bodyparser:

```
eapp.use(bodyParser.json(), app);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `app` instance created using the `dialogflow` function can be used like an Express Request handler function. Thus, you can call it with the Express `request` and `response` object to handle the request.

In the run function for your `Agent` class, you can do something like

```es6
run() {
  const request = ...; // Express request object
  const response = ...; // Express response object
  const app = ...; // app instance created using the dialogflow function
  app(request, response); // call app with the Express objects
}
```

Then when you deployed this server to a public HTTPS endpoint, you can set the fulfillment url in Dialogflow to something like:

`https://subdomain.domain.tld/actions` where `/actions` was the post endpoint you listened to in the code.